# Play song at onmouseover and stop song at onmouseout

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I am working on a onmouseover to play a song for a school project. I already found code for onmouseover and onmouseout but with Alerts its still not working.

If you can help me it would be great. Many thanks!

```
document.getElementById("RockButton").onmouseover = function() {
   mouseOver()
};
 document.getElementById("RockButton").onmouseout = function() {
   mouseOut()
};

function mouseOver() {
   alert('Hello out there!')
}
function mouseOut() {
   alert('Hello out there!')
}
```

---

```
<div id="PaginaDrieTatjana" style="display:none;">
  <h1>Kies soort dans</h1>

  <div id="Rock">
    <h3>Rock Dance</h3>
    <img src="Tatjana/Een.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="RockButton">
        <p>Kiezen</p>
    </div>
  </div >

  <div id="Pop">
    <h3>Pop Dance</h3>
    <img src="Tatjana/Twee.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="PopButton">
        <p>Kiezen</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: as long as the events are working you need to work on the "html" side and then play the song. Can you please show us the relevant html part?

Comment: yes i will add html code. but its not much. Please let me know if you need to see more code.

Comment: the HTML layout is fine, but you will need to add the songs first, for such a task, you can take a look at the official MDN about the media elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video); under the section "controlling media playback" you will also find the javascript needed to either start, stop or pause the music. In a nutshell, just add the <audio> tag pointing to the mp3 files you need to play, and add the play / pause event on the mouseover and mouseleave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery for simplify things, define class for the button and get  audio tag element attributes to play or pause.

```
<div id="Rock">
     <h3>Rock Dance</h3> 
    <img src="Tatjana/Een.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="Button">
        <p>Kiezen</p>
        <audio id="RockDanceAudio" src="rock_audio.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="POP">
     <h3>Rock Dance</h3> 
    <img src="Tatjana/Een.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="Button">
        <p>ROFL</p>
        <audio id="PopDanceAudio" src="pop_audio.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

and use this script

```
$('.Button').mouseover(function () {
    $audio_tag_id = $(this).find('audio').attr('id');
    document.getElementById($audio_tag_id).play();
});
$('.Button').mouseout(function () {
    $audio_tag_id = $(this).find('audio').attr('id');
    document.getElementById($audio_tag_id).pause();
});
```

it will work for n number of buttons, happy coding :)

Comment: One Question, If i have more buttons and for each i want to do the same. Correct me if i am wrong but that is not possible with your code. correct?

Comment: yes its not possible with the above code for more buttons, use jQuery for simplify the things, check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this guide:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

It provides code for both HTML and JavaScript to implement audio player within your webpage. You'll just have to paste the right components in your snippet.